# What do numbers in braces e.g. "{0}" mean?

Tags: vb.net, string, function, curly-braces

I've been looking around but having great difficulty finding the answer to this question as the thing I'm looking for is so unspecific.

I've seen a lot of code which uses `{0}` in it, and I still can't work out what it's doing. Here's an example:

```
Dim literal As String = "CatDogFence"
Dim substring As String = literal.Substring(6)
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", substring)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", substring)
```

Is the same as

```
Console.WriteLine("Substring: " & substring)
```

When using `Console.WriteLine`, `{n}` will insert the `n`th argument into the string, then write it.

A more complex example can be seen here:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}{2}", "Stack", "Over", "flow")
```

It will print `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you! Though I have to ask, why did you edit out my question about saying hello on StackOverflow, because I am a little mystified as to why that's a problem? :P

Comment: @LeoKing You're welcome :) Here at Stack Overflow we don't want greetings and "thanks" in our questions, they just distract from the question. (read more [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts))

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Seems like quite a controversy on that link. I personally can't see anything wrong with it, as I hate to seem too demanding and petty on any site, but I won't be a kerfuffle if that's how the community wants it!

Comment: @LeoKing Well, before my edit, half of your question had nothing to do with the question :P But don't worry, I was confused at first too; you'll get used to it :)

Answer (score 3):

Console.WriteLine() and String.Format() use that syntax.
It allows you to inject a variable into a string, for example:

```
dim name = "james"
String.Format("Hello {0}", name)
```

That string will be "Hello james"

Using Console.Writeline:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}",name)
```

That will write "Hello james"

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense :).

Answer (score 1):

It's a placeholder. Beginning at the second parameter (substring in your case), they are included in the given string in the given order. This way you avoid long string concatenations using + operator and can do easier language localization, because you can pull the compete string including the placeholders to some external resource file etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is called composite formatting and is supported by many methods, Console.WriteLine being one.  Besides indexed placeholders there are other features available.  Here is a link to the documentation that shows some of the other features of composite formatting.

[Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)